# How to automatically do another task after progress bar reaches 100% in java

Tags: java, progress-bar

I have created a progress bar in my project that loads whilst words are being created in a database. Now this works fine and here is some code (Note: Not all code is shown as it is confidential)

Structure of form:

```
/**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            { 
                try
                {
                    Welcome frame = new Welcome();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } 
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //**************************************************
    // CREATE THE FORM                                 *
    //**************************************************
    public CreateWindow() 
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 163);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        //Progress Bar
        JProgressBar progress = new JProgressBar();
        progress.setBounds(5, 41, 424, 17);
        progress.setStringPainted(true);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        //Label above the Progress Bar
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Loop progress is: ");
        label.setBounds(5, 5, 424, 14);
        contentPane.add(label);
        contentPane.add(progress);
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        //Will be used for updating the progress bar 
        ProgressWorker worker = new ProgressWorker(progress);
```

The Progress bar:

```
    private static class ProgressWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> 
        { //Swing worker class for updating the progress bar

            private final JProgressBar progress; //declaration for progress bar

            public ProgressWorker(JProgressBar progress)
            { 
                this.progress = progress;

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception
            {
             //Task performed here
    }
    System.out.println("i = " + recordLoop);
                    final int progr = ((int) ((100L * (recordLoop - firstRecord)) / (lastRecord-firstRecord)));
                    publish(progr);

                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            //This is the process of how the progress bar will load 
            protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) 
            {
                progress.setValue(chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1));
                super.process(chunks); 
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() 
            {
                progress.setValue(100); //This is the value when process is complete 
}
}
```

Now this is well and good as it works as intended but now I want another task to automatically run after the progress bar reached 100%. This is where the problem occurs. Here is what I have tried:

```
protected void done() 
        {
            progress.setValue(100); //This is the value when process is complete  

            if (int progress == 100) {
                //Do task here 
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

This is not the only way I've tried. I have also tried adding the code under a new signature method and I have also tried putting the if statement in the doInBackground() method. I am new to progress bars so sorry for any silly mistakes. Is there a way to be able to do this?

If my idea is incorrect I have also tried this without an if statement by running the task after the first task but the problem here is that I have a for loop in the task performed in the doInBackground() method and **I don't want this second task to be included in the for loop**.

Comment: You're thinking about this all wrong. You want to move on to the next task after the first one completes, *not* when the progress bar says it has completed. There's a big difference between the actual *business locic* and the progress bar, which is just a visualization.

Comment: Ok then I will update my question

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart - I have updated my question.